# jenkins hide certain build parameters from general users

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

I have a project based security enabled for my jobs. And based on user being admin / non-admin would like to show / hide certain build parameters.

Can anyone suggest an approach to tackle this requirements or are there any plugins for this?

Thanks!! Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a feature directly, but there is a workaround.

- Configure "**non-admin**" job with only the parameters that non-admins should see.
- Give that job security so that non-admins can build it.
- Configure second "**admin**" job
- Give that second job security so that only admins can build it.

In the Job Configuration of the second "**admin**" job, you need to:

- Define all parameters (admin and non-admin)
- Use **[Parameterized Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)** plugin ("Trigger/call builds on other projects" build action) to trigger "non-admin" job
- Configure <kbd>Add Parameters</kbd> -> <kbd>Current build parameters</kbd>
- That's it.

In the Job Configuration of the first "**non-admin**" job, you need to:

- Define just non-admin parameters, making sure their names are **exactly same** as overlapping parameters from "admin" job
- Configure the rest of the job as you normally would.
- All parameters, even those that are passed from the triggering "admin" job are available as environment variables (even if they are not explicitly defined in "non-admin" job)